# How to add an index from command line to DynamoDB after table was created

Tags: amazon-web-services, indexing, amazon-dynamodb, command-line-interface

Could you please point me to an appropriate documentation topic or provide an example how to add index to DynamoDB as far as I couldn't find any related info.

According to this blog: http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-dynamodb-update-online-indexing-reserved-capacity-improvements/?sc_ichannel=em&sc_icountry=global&sc_icampaigntype=launch&sc_icampaign=em_130867660&sc_idetail=em_1273527421&ref_=pe_411040_130867660_15 it seems to be possible to do it with UI, however there are no mentions about CLI interface usages.

Thanks in advance,
Yevhenii

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `aws` command has help for every level of subcommand. For example, you can run `aws help` to get a list of all service names and discover the name `dynamodb`. Then you can `aws dynamodb help` to find the list of DDB commands and find that `update-table` is a likely culprit. Finally, `aws dynamodb update-table help` shows you the flags needed to add a global secondary index.

Answer (score 1):

The AWS CLI documentation is really poor and lacks examples. Evidently AWS is promoting the SDK or the console.

This should work for updating

```
aws dynamodb update-table  --table-name Test \
  --attribute-definitions AttributeName=City,AttributeType=S AttributeName=State,AttributeType=S \
  --global-secondary-index-updates \
  "Create={"IndexName"="state-index", "KeySchema"=[ {"AttributeName"="State", "KeyType"="HASH" }], "Projection"={"ProjectionType"="INCLUDE", "NonKeyAttributes"="City"}, "ProvisionedThroughput"= {"ReadCapacityUnits"=1, "WriteCapacityUnits"=1}   }"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shell function to do this that sets the R/W caps, and optionally handles --global-secondary-index-updates if an index name is provided

```
dynamodb_set_caps() {
 #  [ "$1" ] || fail_exit "Missing table name"
 #  [ "$3" ] || fail_exit "Missing read capacity"
 #  [ "$3" ] || fail_exit "Missing write capacity"
  if [ "$4" ] ; then 
    aws dynamodb update-table  --region $region --table-name ${1} \
      --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=${2},WriteCapacityUnits=${3} \
      --global-secondary-index-updates \
      "Update={"IndexName"="${4}", "ProvisionedThroughput"= {"ReadCapacityUnits"=${2}, "WriteCapacityUnits"=${3}} }"
  else
    aws dynamodb update-table  --region $region --table-name ${1} \
      --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=${2},WriteCapacityUnits=${3}
  fi
}
```

Completely agree that the aws docs are lacking in this area

Answer (score 0):

Here is reference for creating a global secondary index:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/getting-started-step-6.html

However the example only provides the creation of an index for a single primary key.

This code helped me to create a global secondary index for a composite primary key:

```
aws dynamodb update-table \
--table-name YourTableName \
--attribute-definitions AttributeName=GSI1PK,AttributeType=S \
AttributeName=GSI1SK,AttributeType=S \
AttributeName=createdAt,AttributeType=S \
--global-secondary-index-updates \
"[{\"Create\":{\"IndexName\": \"GSI1\",\"KeySchema\":[{\"AttributeName\":\"GSI1PK\",\"KeyType\":\"HASH\"},{\"AttributeName\":\"GSI1SK\",\"KeyType\":\"RANGE\"}], \
\"ProvisionedThroughput\": {\"ReadCapacityUnits\": 5, \"WriteCapacityUnits\": 5      },\"Projection\":{\"ProjectionType\":\"ALL\"}}}]" --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

*A note in the bottom line considers that you are creating this index in your local database. If not, just delete it.*